# Why won't the SimpleXML deserialize Attribute?

Tags: android, soap, simple-framework

I am working with a UPnP device, that exposes services I want to access. I am using `SimpleXML` for marshalling data. So far so good, except that now I am stuck, again.

Given **the XML below**:

```
<DIDL-Lite xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/" xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <item id="123456" parentID="1" restricted="1">
        <res protocolInfo="http-get:*:video/mpeg:*">http://stream_resource/media/index.m3u8</res>
        <upnp:callSign>My Call Sign here</upnp:callSign>
        <upnp:class>object.item.videoItem.videoBroadcast</upnp:class>
        <dc:title>My Title Here</dc:title>
    </item>
</DIDL-Lite>
```

I have the following **POJOs**:

Root:

```
@Root(name = "DIDL-Lite")
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace(reference = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/"),
        @Namespace(reference = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/", prefix = "upnp"),
        @Namespace(reference = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", prefix = "dc")
})
public class ResultObject {

  @ElementList(name = "item")
  private List<ObjectItem> listItems;
}
```

ObjectItem:

```
@Root(name = "item")
public class ObjectItem {

  @Attribute(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @Attribute(name = "parentID")
  private String parentID;

  @Attribute(name = "restricted")
  private String restricted;

  @Element(name = "res")//something appears to be wrong here ! this element is not actually parsed ?
  private ResourceInfo resInfo;

  @Element(name = "callSign")
  private String callSign;

  @Element(name = "class")
  private String upnpClass;

  @Element(name = "title")
  private String dcTitle;
}
```

ResourceInfo:

```
@Root(name = "res")
public class ResourceInfo {

  @Attribute(name = "protocolInfo")
  private String protocolInfo;
}
```

This is the **parse error** that I get :  W/System.err: org.simpleframework.xml.core.AttributeException: Attribute 'protocolInfo' does not have a match in class xx.yyy.ObjectItem at line 1.

**After some digging**, I tried to deserialize that value into an `ElementMap` like so:

ObjectItem:

```
@Root(name = "item")
public class ObjectItem {

  @Attribute(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @Attribute(name = "parentID")
  private String parentID;

  @Attribute(name = "restricted")
  private String restricted;

  @ElementMap(entry = "res", key = "protocolInfo", attribute = true, inline = true)
  //so what is actually going on here?
  private Map<String, String> elementMap;

  @Element(name = "callSign")
  private String callSign;

  @Element(name = "class")
  private String upnpClass;

  @Element(name = "title")
  private String dcTitle;
```

**Still getting** the parse error.

Any hints?

Comment: Why you don't use cling for upnp?
http://4thline.org/projects/cling/

Comment: @PogonetsAnton I tried integrating cling but gave up for 2 reasons: mainly, I lack experience working with UPNP and cling seemed heavy for me as a starter. Secondly, the UPNP device I am working with uses some custom discovery and authentication mechanisms, and I did not manage to establish a connection with the device using cling. With that aside, Cling is an awesome library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not in ObjectItem it is how ObjectItems stored in ResultObject.

Use `@ElementList(name = "item", inline = true)` on `List<ObjectItem> listItems;` instead of `@ElementList(name = "item")`

Or just `@ElementList(inline = true)` name is not required in this case.

See differences:

[`@ElementList`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#list)

[`@ElementList(inline = true)`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#inline)

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested and solved my issue. On top of this, I also "inlined" all my`@ElementList`. Thank you !